# loopback tx.notifyObserversOf not a function error

Tags: javascript, loopback, loopback3

In Loopback3, i am migrating from oracle to postgres and switched connectors and changed models just fine. Only error i have is this:

```
TypeError: tx.notifyObserversOf is not a function
at Timeout._onTimeout (api\node_modules\loopback-connector\lib\transaction.js:124:12)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

`api\node_modules\loopback-connector\lib\transaction.js:124`

`tx.notifyObserversOf('timeout', context, function(err) {`

How do i get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

try installing the loopback-connector-postgresql@3.9.1 version, that worked for me.

I think it is due to the installed node version, I'm  using 10.17